# MySQL WHERE from an array

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array with these values, 1 & 5 and I am trying to generate a mysql query to return all of these values id, I hope that makes sense, here is my code:

```
if(isset($filterOpts['location'])){
                        foreach($filterOpts['location'] as $row => $value){
                                $where .= " AND `rb_locations`.`locationId` = " . $value;
                        }
                }
```

this will return AND `rb_locations`.`locationId` = 1 AND `rb_locations`.`locationId` = 5

I am guess that AND and AND are causing my problems. how do I fix this? When I remove the 5, it returns results.

I didnt post the rest of the query because I know its not the issue :)

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [`IN` clause](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm). It checks whether a value is within a set of values:

```
if (isset($filterOpts['location'])) {

   $locationIds = implode(',', $filterOpts['location']);

   $where .= " AND `rb_locations`.`locationId` IN (" . $locationIds . ") ";

}
```